# Repeat characters in a string

Tags: ruby, string

I know this is a simple problem, but for some reason it wont click.  I want to repeat characters in a string for a fixed amount.  For example:

```
str = 'abcde'
temp = ''
x = 8
for i in 0..x
    if str[i].nil?
        temp << ''
    else
        temp << str[i]
    end
end
```

Except I get no input.  What I need is:

> abcdeabc

Please, any help would be appreciated.  If there is a better working way to do this instead of my not working naive approach, I would like to know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `ljust` should do it:

```
str = 'abcde'

str.ljust(8, str)
# => "abcdeabc" 

str.ljust(12, str)
# => "abcdeabcdeab"
```

Comment: +1, but maybe `''.ljust(8, str)` is somewhat better (taking care of lengths < str.length).

Comment: Not working for not ascii character in ruby1.8 though. Best answer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to repeat a string a few times, use `*`. We can combine that with slicing to get this solution:

```
def repfill(str, n)
    nrep = (Float(n) / str.length).ceil
    return (str * nrep)[0...n]
end
```

Example:

```
irb(main):030:0> repfill('abcde', 8)
=> "abcdeabc"
```

---

As for your solution, what you are missing is a *modulo* to repeat the string from the beginning:

```
str = 'abcde'
temp = ''
x = 8
for i in 0...x # note ... to exclude last element of range
    temp << str[i % str.length]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using [slicing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-slice)

```
def repeat_x_chars(str, x)
  # special cases
  return str if x == 0
  return ""  if str.length == 0

  return str + str[0..(str.length % x)] # slicing
end
```

Answer (score 1):

analog str_repeat

```
"abcde" * 3   
#-> "abcdeabcdeabcde"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one-liner:

```
res = (str * (x / str.length)) + str[0...(x%str.length)]
```

Comment: Your integer division will throw off the result.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen; No, it won't because of Rubys automatic integer division instead of float division.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: It's intentional! Doing it how I did it is basically an automatic `floor` call.

Comment: try running your solution with `x = 23`

Comment: whoops, I modified `str` in one of my previous calls. My mistake.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: No prob. Just wanted to show that my code worked.